# Writing to a memory mapped file created by Windows service does not change this memory on service side

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-services, memory-mapped-files

I have Windows service that creates memory mapped file

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { 0 };
sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;

const wchar_t* sdd = L"D:"
        L"(D;OICI;GA;;;BG)" //Deny guests
        L"(D;OICI;GA;;;AN)" //Deny anonymous
        L"(A;OICI;GRGWGX;;;AU)" //Allow read, write and execute for Users
        L"(A;OICI;GA;;;BA)"; //Allow all for Administrators

ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW(sdd, SDDL_REVISION_1, &sa->lpSecurityDescriptor, NULL);

shmem = ::CreateFileMappingA(
        INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
        &sa,
        PAGE_READWRITE,
        0,
        sizeof(BYTE),
        "Global\\my_memory"
    );
PBYTE pShared = (PBYTE)MapViewOfFile(shmem, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, sizeof(DWORD));

pShared[0] = 0;

// I use Event to notify service that user application changed mapped memory
HANDLE hEvent = OpenEventA(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, false, "Global\\my_event")
WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);

// !!!! Here is a problem - a byte in mapped memory is always zero
// even though I change it in user application
printf("pShared value: %d\n", pShared[0]);
```

And user application that writes to this memory mapped file. But the changes in mapped memory are not reflected in my service, the memory remains unchanged.

```
shmem = OpenFileMappingA(
        FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE,   // read/write access
        FALSE,                 // do not inherit the name
        "Global\\my_memory");              // name of mapping object

PBYTE pShared = (PBYTE)MapViewOfFile(shmem, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, sizeof(BYTE));

// I don't get any errors here, I can write to this memory
pShared[0] = 0xff;

HANDLE hEvent = OpenEventA(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, "Global\\my_event");
SetEvent(hEvent);
```

Can someone explain why user application can't change memory created by service?
I suppose it has something to do with Session 0 isolation of the service, but I didn't find any info that definitely proves it.

Comment: It has something to do with access rights since services are high level protected objects in windows. It also seems it cannot work if you use default security, have a look here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga

Comment: There is no error checking in your code, fixing that would be a start.

Comment: and where you create "Global\\my_event" ?

Comment: @RbMm It is created  by the service in other part of the program

Comment: @Gold What do you mean by default security? I populate SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure with my settings, so I suppose I am not using default setting
BTW. If service writes to the mapped memory the application can see those changes in memory

Comment: @Cycledo - why you again open event in service, instead  save and use handle from create ? from your code probably OpenEventA fail in service or event already in signal state, before another process set it

Comment: @RbMm You are right, opening an event again in the service is excessive, but it works. 
But it stiil was an issue with synchronization. Application were changing memory after I read it in the service, that's why I didn't see changes.

Comment: in what problem debug this ? attach debugger both to service and app, sure that when app call `SetEvent` service thread inside `WaitForSingleObject`

Comment: @Cycledo, I was talking about 'SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { 0 }; It seems initialized but I'd rather use something like that to copy my own sa copied by something like "GetSecurityInfo". Anyway Win32 is an old story for me due to this kind of obscure undocumented "feature". You may discover it's only due to some inapropriate parameter. Also check your function return errors !